# included do ..... end (wrong no of arguments) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am implementing a module and including that in a my class by using the RoR ActiveSupport::Concern feature. I am using included do .... end block in that module but facing an error "wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)" for "included do" line.

```
module Icecream
  extend ActiveSupport::Concerns

  included do  #throws error wrong no of arguments(0 for 1))
    has_many :flavours
    scope :icecreams, ->{where("has_icecreams = ?", true)}
  end
.
.
.
.
.
end
```

Does included do block even needs arguments?

Comment: It works without arguments, see the example at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html (2nd code block)

Comment: Ya Stefan i know it generally works without arguments ,dont know what's wrong in this case.

Comment: @ArvindMehra it's ActiveSupport::Concern and not ActiveSupport::Concerns

Answer (score 24, accepted):

oh.... got it fixed...

Stupid typo mistake

extend ActiveSupport::**Concerns**  should be **Concern**

Comment: Saved me from a huge future headache. Thanks for posting the solution!

Answer (score 16):

You could have the same problem if you do `include ActiveSupport::Concern` instead of `extend ActiveSupport::Concern`.